# Is my query for facebook like Wall efficient or I misconfigured it

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a Facebook like wall using the query below.

```
"SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS `table`, 
            `comment_post_id` AS `feed_id`, 
            `blog_id` AS `from_blog`, 
            `comment_author` AS `author`, 
            `comment_content_stripped` AS `feed_title`, 
            `comment_content` AS `post_content_s`, 
            `type` AS `type`, 
            null AS `object_type`,
            `comment_date_gmt` AS `date` 
            FROM `wp_site_comments`
            UNION
            SELECT 2 AS `table`, 
            `post_id` AS `feed_id`, 
            null AS `from_blog`,  
            `blog_id` AS `author`, 
            `post_title` AS `feed_title`, 
            `post_content_stripped` AS `post_content_s`, 
            `post_type` AS `type`, 
            null AS `object_type`,
            `post_published_gmt` AS `date` 
            FROM `wp_site_posts`
        UNION
        SELECT 3 AS `table`, 
            `object_id` AS `feed_id`, 
            `blog_id` AS `from_blog`,  
            `user_id` AS `author`, 
            null AS `feed_title`, 
            null AS `post_content_s`, 
            `type` AS `type`, 
            `object_type` AS `object_type`,
            `date_added` AS `date` 
            FROM `wp_global_likes`
        UNION
        SELECT 4 AS `table`, 
            `object_id` AS `feed_id`, 
            null AS `from_blog`,  
            `user_id` AS `author`, 
            null AS `feed_title`, 
            null AS `post_content_s`, 
            `type` AS `type`, 
            `object_type` AS `object_type`,
            `date_added` AS `date` 
            FROM `wp_global_followers`
        ) AS tb
        ORDER BY `date` DESC"
```

The result returns correct but I wonder if the query is efficient or there is a better one to accomplish this.

Comment: How should we know?  You don't show the table schema, the relationships, what indexes are used, etc.

Comment: yup, we need more info, +1 for oldProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

You can du an `ORDER BY` withjout the need for subqueries:

```
(SELECT …)
UNION
(SELECT …)
UNION
(SELECT …)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Quoting from [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html):

> To use an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause to sort or limit the entire `UNION` result, parenthesize the individual `SELECT` statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one.

And since you probably can be certain that there won't be any duplicate rows, you can change your implicit `UNION DISTINCT` to `UNION ALL` to avoid the unneccessary removal of duplicates.